# Connect two PsychoPy Scripts via TCP

Tags: python, tcp, tcpserver, psychopy

**What am I trying to achieve?:**

I am currently programming a psychological experiment using PsychoPy where 2 participants should perform the task on separate computers and chatting with each other on jointly making a decision.

For now though, I just want to figure out how to connect to psychopy scripts, i.e., how psychopy script A could send a signal to psychopy script B. I was thinking to use TCP communication to do this.

**Problem:**

Psychopy script A sends the signal to the server but the Psychopy script B does not receive the message in the end.

I am very new to programming and realizing that this might be too big of a task for a novice but I'm quite deep into the project now. That's why I would really appreciate the help!

**Expectation:**

Script A prompts an input via a dialog box and sends it to the server using a thread, the server reads and sends the message to the receiving Script B.

**What I tried:**

I found some nice code on other posts for building a server and 2 clients that communicate together and this worked. I wanted to use the architecture to just send a basic signal from Script A to Script B as a first step for now. However, when I used and modified it a bit to implement it in PsychoPy, the message from Script A will reach the server but never reaches Script B. I tried to print the signal in the cmd interface of the server and it reaches it, however, somehow the receiving while loop in the receiving Script always has an error.

**Setup:**

I am using 2 computers, one for each script and they both succeed to connect to the server.

My setup software -
OS: Win10 |
PsychoPy version: 2020.2.5, 64bit | Python version: 3.10 |
Psychopy standard standalone? (y/n) Y

Please find the code below for the sending client (Psychopy), the server (Basic Python) and the receiving client (Psychopy):

Thank you in advance!

**CODES**

**Sending client (Psychopy):**

```
from psychopy import visual, event, core, data 
from psychopy.visual import textbox #import textbox library for textual stimuli
import threading
import socket
from psychopy import gui
from psychopy import __version__ 

# Connecting To Server
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 5005))

def write():
    while True:
        message = str(signal)
        client.send(message.encode('ascii'))

# Create dialogbox to record the signal
dlg = gui.Dlg(title="My experiment", pos=(200, 400))
dlg.addText('Make your decision', color='Blue')
dlg.addField('Decision:', tip='or subject code')
signal = dlg.show()

if dlg.OK:
    print(signal)
else:
    print('User cancelled')

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

**Server (plain python)**

```
import threading
import socket

host = 'localhost' # localhost
port = 5005

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.settimeout(20) #I tried to increase allowed time before timeout but it doesn't help
server.listen()

clients = []
signals = []

# Sending Messages To All Connected Clients
def broadcast(signal):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(signal)
        print(signal) #to check if the signal even reaches the server and it does

# Handling Messages From Clients
def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            # Broadcasting Messages
            signal = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(signal)
        except:
            # Removing And Closing Clients
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            signal = signals[index]
            broadcast(signal.encode('ascii'))
            signals.remove(signal)
            break

# Receiving / Listening Function
def receive():
    while True:
        # Accept Connection
        client, address = server.accept()
        print("Connected with {}".format(str(address)))

        signal = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        signals.append(signal)
        clients.append(client)

        broadcast(signal.encode('ascii'))
        client.send('Connected to server!'.encode('ascii'))

        # Start Handling Thread For Client
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


print("Server is listening...")
receive()
```

**Receiving client (Psychopy)**

```
from psychopy import visual, event, core, data 
from psychopy.visual import textbox #import textbox library for textual stimuli
import threading
import socket
from psychopy import gui
from psychopy import __version__

win = visual.Window(screen =0, fullscr = False, allowGUI=True, units='pix', color = 'black')

# Connecting To Server
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 5005))

# Listening to Server
def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            # Receive Message From Server
            signal = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if signal is not None:
                message = visual.TextStim(win, str(signal))
                message.draw()
                win.flip()
                print(signal) #To make sure, the signal was received but it never happens
                
        except:  
            # Close Connection When Error
            print("An error occured!")   #This always happens when I run it 
            client.close()
            break


# Starting Thread For Listening
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

event.waitKeys()
```

Comment: TCP is not a message-based protocol.  It is a stream of bytes.  A single `send` can be received as two or more `recv` and vice versa.  The only guarantee is the bytes are received in the same order sent.  Data should be buffered and higher level protocols need to be designed to extract complete messages from the stream.  Also see [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) which wraps a socket in a file-like stream, which can be used to read newline-terminated lines, or read an exact amount of bytes from the stream.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! 

We found a way to circumvent the chat messaging. Now, we only need to figure out how one Psychopy Script can send a single string to another Psychopy script which behaves according to the string received. 

Is this possible with TCP as there is just a simple transmission of information required? And do you know resources on how to implement this in psychopy? Thank you!